# visual studio 2012 build error namespace

Tags: .net, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm a complete novice in Visual Studio so perhaps this is a very rudimentary question. I'm a user experience designer so programming isn't really my specialty. I'm currently trying to build an app that we created and do some Q&A testing. When I attempt to build the application and tested I get a number of errors however I don't understand what the errors are or how to resolve them?

I get 27 errors that look more or less just like this but with a different 'items'

> The type or namespace name 'BindableBase' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\WindowsApps\Win8_Enterprise_Studio\WestJet\WestJetTablet\Easyjet.FlightTracker.W8App\Model\FeedData.cs
>   Oltiva.FlightTracker.W8App

Could someone please give me some perspective here on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Assembly which holds `BindableBase` was able to build. If it doesn't build, other projects with references to it might complain, as you've seen.

Comment: How do i go about doing that? like i said i really have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Hard to say. Are there any missing items in the solution explorer? Did you open a solution file or project?

Comment: Ive downloaded the latest versions of the files contained within the folder so I'm assuming yes. Then I find the appropriate .snl file and then attempt to build the app. Same errors every time.

Comment: Just to make sure, check the Solution Explorer `Ctrl-R` for anything missing. Something missing will have a yellow flag on it. Is there a project called `BindableBase`? If no, do a search `Ctrl-F` for BindableBase (search entire solution) and find the project which defines it.

Comment: Also, you can build each project one at a time and see if any fail.